# No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

while trying to start the app, its getting terminated. I'm trying to do oneToMany & ManyToOne mappings. Someone please help me to start the app successfully, here I am using Mysql adding the necessary code snippets for the analysis. I have created Repository interfaces for both the entities as well. Kindly help me to get this issue resolved.

**Error:**

```
No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:20.359+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

**logs:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v3.2.1)[0;39m

[2m2024-01-06T20:31:17.636+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mc.j.e.EmployeeAddressApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting EmployeeAddressApplication using Java 17.0.8.1 with PID 14920 (C:\Users\kamak\Downloads\employee-address\employee-address\target\classes started by kamak in C:\Users\kamak\Downloads\employee-address\employee-address)
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:17.639+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mc.j.e.EmployeeAddressApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:18.096+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:18.122+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:18.458+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:18.514+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:18.554+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:18.777+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:18.818+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:19.207+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@463afa6e
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:19.209+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:20.211+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:20.359+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:20.742+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mc.j.e.EmployeeAddressApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started EmployeeAddressApplication in 3.537 seconds (process running for 4.325)
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:20.759+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [ionShutdownHook][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:20.764+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [ionShutdownHook][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
[2m2024-01-06T20:31:20.780+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m14920[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS] [ionShutdownHook][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.jagan</groupId>
  <artifactId>employee-address</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>employee-address</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.application.name=EMPLOYEE-ADDRESS
server.port=8084
```

**Address.java**

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Data
//@AllArgsConstructor
//@NoArgsConstructor
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int addressId;
    private String houseNumber;
    private String city;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id")
    private Employee employee;

}
```

**Employee.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Data
//@AllArgsConstructor
//@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int empId;
    private String empName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<Address> address;
}
```

Comment: connection string perhaps

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
HHH000489: No JTA platform available
```

is not an error. Just a message logged at INFO level. I get the same every time.

Secondly: from your `pom.xml` it is not a Web application. No embedded Tomcat server will be started. There is nothing to do for your Spring Boot application but to start properly and shutdown without any error.

Everything works as expected.

**Solution**

Depending on your requirements add some code and/or dependencies because currently your application seems to do nothing.

Comment: For example, add `spring-boot-starter-web`